# onKeyDown() error, al presionar atrás, pregunte si deseo cerrar

Tags: java, android

Tengo `onKeyDown` para cerrar mi aplicación, resulta que al presionar, se cierra de manera inmediata.
Lo que necesito es que al presionar atrás, pregunte si deseo cerrar.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode==event.KEYCODE_BACK){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Desea Salir De La APlicacion")
                .setPositiveButton("si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: ¿Desde qué contexto intentas esto? Activity, Fragment... Quizá convendría hacerlo desde `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Importante agregar cual es el error se muestra en el LogCat!

Comment: esta fuera de oncreate , cuando la pego adrendo me sale error del evento , tendra algun codigo para preguntar para salir que pueda utilizar.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho una consulta este mata la aplicacion cuando sale y no la deja en segundo plano

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que deseas:

> Lo que necesito es que al presionar atrás, pregunte si deseo cerrar.

no debes usar `onKeyDown()` , debes usar `onBackPressed()` para detectar en verdad cuando presionas el botón para regresar, dentro de este método debes agregar el mensaje:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("¿Salir?")
            .setMessage("¿Estas seguro que deseas salir?")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    finish(); //finaliza Activity.
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]